# How to set the value for all elements using a variable in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, input-field

Setting the value for all input fields of a class `foo` is easy:

```
$('#long .path .to .foo').val('...');
```

But now I need to manipulate the `foo` fields at multiple places, so I saved it as object as want to use it like this:

```
foo = $('#long .path .to .foo');
foo.val('...');
```

When I assign the value within the function, where I use it, it works. But when this doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    foo = $('#long .path .to .foo');
    bar();
}
function bar() {
    foo.val('...');
}
```

And it's not about the scope, since this works:

```
function bar() {
    foo.first().val('...'); // or last() 
}
```

**How to set the `value` of all elements of a `class` using a jQuery object saved to a variable (outside the current scope)?**

Comment: Where do you *declare* `foo`?

Comment: Try using `$(foo).val('...')`, does that fix it?

Comment: @Madbreaks If you mean declare then when declaration is missing the variable is global when defined like `foo = $('#long .path .to .foo');`

Comment: @Madbreaks Outside of the function, above it: `$(document).ready(function() { foo = $('#long .path .to .foo'); bar(); }`

Comment: @sbonkosky why do you think that will work? That's not logical

Comment: @user1533609 correct, however it's unclear from op's post if where `foo` is declared.

Comment: @sbonkosky No, it doesn't work.

Comment: @user1533609 Wrapping the variable in `$()` will make it a jQuery object, allowing mmethods like `val()` to be used. Why would that not be logical?

Comment: @sbonkosky It's already a jQuery object: `foo = $('#long .path .to .foo');`.

Comment: @automatix Ah, here I thought you always had to wrap the variable in `$()` to use it. Learned something new!

Comment: This works for me https://jsfiddle.net/697n5ue7/1/

Comment: If you can make a jsfiddle then maybe we can detect something by looking at your HTML and JS

Comment: Are you getting errors? What about this "doesn't work" for you?

Comment: @DaniP Thank you! I'm actually wondering, why the same isn't working for me now... Trying to find a difference...

Comment: @scrappedcola With "doesn't work" I meant, that the input field's value doesn't get updated. But now I see: It _does_ work, bu only for the first item. And when I declare the variable in the function, it works as expected (sets all fields' values).

Comment: Guys, first of all thank you for trying to help me! I think, I've finally found the differenc between DaniP's fiddle and my code. In my case the first input field is common HTML and all the other ones are generated on the fly -- _after_ the `document` has been loaded. Its why it works for the first and only the first element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the fields are generated by JavaScript -- *after* the document has been loaded. Only the input item is static, that's why it work for it.

The solution is to move the `foo` declaration to a callback and use is in the function(s) instead of the variable, so that the relevant input items list is fetched every time, when it should be manipulated:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    foo = function() {
        return $('#long .path .to .foo');
    };
    bar();
}
function bar() {
    foo().val('...');
}
```